# Neo4j update nodes from CSV file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to update the already existing nodes with new data and create a new one if the node doesn't exist. I am trying to do that with the following query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Zona5/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/cd1_5.csv' AS     line1
MERGE (c:Company {companyNumber:line1.companyNumber})
WITH c, line1
MERGE (ca:CompanyAddress)
ON CREATE SET ca.county=line1.County
ON MATCH SET ca.county=line1.County
ON CREATE SET ca.country=line1.Country
ON MATCH SET ca.country=line1.Country
ON CREATE SET ca.postCode=line1.postCode 
ON MATCH SET ca.postCode=line1.postCode
ON CREATE SET ca.poBox=line1.POBox
ON MATCH SET ca.poBox=line1.POBox
ON CREATE SET ca.careOf=line1.CareOf
ON MATCH SET ca.careOf=line1.CareOf
ON CREATE SET ca.addressLine1=line1.AddressLine1
ON MATCH SET ca.addressLine1=line1.AddressLine1
ON CREATE SET ca.addressLine2=line1.AddressLine2
ON MATCH SET ca.addressLine2=line1.AddressLine2
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_COMPANY_ADDRESS]->(ca)
```

The query is running for a long time but the database size does not increase.

Am I doing something wrong here and is there another way to update the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MERGE` clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) does exactly this. From the docs:

> MERGE either matches existing nodes and binds them, or it creates new data and binds that. It’s like a combination of MATCH and CREATE that additionally allows you to specify what happens if the data was matched or created.

So let's look at your query. This line:

```
MERGE (c:Company {companyNumber:line1.companyNumber})
```

ill create a new node with the label `Company` if there is no existing node with the label `Company` that has the property `companyNumber` with a value of whatever `line1.companyNumber` is for this row in your CSV file. This is similar to the a primary key in a relational database. `companyNumber` is the thing that uniquely identifies a `Company` node and you don't want to create duplicate nodes with the same value for this property.

You should [also create a uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#_using_unique_constraints_with_merge) to enforce this at the database schema level:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Company) ASSERT c.companyNumber IS UNIQUE;
```

But otherwise this first part looks good.

Now the next part of your query:

```
MERGE (ca:CompanyAddress)
ON CREATE SET ca.county=line1.County
ON MATCH SET ca.county=line1.County
ON CREATE SET ca.country=line1.Country
ON MATCH SET ca.country=line1.Country
ON CREATE SET ca.postCode=line1.postCode 
ON MATCH SET ca.postCode=line1.postCode
ON CREATE SET ca.poBox=line1.POBox
ON MATCH SET ca.poBox=line1.POBox
ON CREATE SET ca.careOf=line1.CareOf
ON MATCH SET ca.careOf=line1.CareOf
ON CREATE SET ca.addressLine1=line1.AddressLine1
ON MATCH SET ca.addressLine1=line1.AddressLine1
ON CREATE SET ca.addressLine2=line1.AddressLine2
ON MATCH SET ca.addressLine2=line1.AddressLine2
```

`MERGE` takes a pattern and will then search the graph to see if this pattern exists, creating data if it does not exist. The pattern you are specifying to MERGE on is a node with the label `CompanyAddress`. This will `MATCH` on **all** nodes with the label `CompanyAddress` regardless of their properties. Then the following `SET` statements will update the properties for **all** `CompanyAddress` nodes. So what you will end up with is that this part of the query will create at most one `CompanyAddress` node and all existing`CompanyAddress` nodes will have the same property values, whatever the last row in your CSV file is.

Instead you should `MERGE` using multiple properties:

```
MERGE (ca:CompanyAddress {
    county: line1.County, 
    country: line1.Country,
    poBox: line1.POBox,
    careof: line1.Careof,
    addressLine1: line1.AddressLine1,
    addressLine2: line1.AddressLine2
})
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_COMPANY_ADDRESS]->(ca)
```

Although note that if one field changes this approach will create a new node for the `CompanyAddress`. If you want to update a field on an address when it changes you'll need to introduce some unique id for the address and `MERGE` on that property.

**UPDATE**

Given the data modeling constraint that each `Company` node is connected to only one `CompanyAddress` node, this query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Zona5/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/cd1_5.csv' AS line1
MERGE (c:Company {companyNumber:line1.companyNumber})
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_COMPANY_ADDRESS]->(ca:CompanyAddress)
SET ca.county=line1.County,
    ca.country=line1.Country,
    ca.postCode=line1.postCode,
    ca.poBox=line1.POBox,
    ca.careOf=line1.CareOf,
    ca.addressLine1=line1.AddressLine1,
    ca.addressLine2=line1.AddressLine2
```

will create `Company`, `CompanyAddress` nodes connected by `HAS_COMPANY_ADDRESS` relationship if they do not exist, and then update the properties of `CompanyAddress`.

Comment: The problem is that there are millions companies to be updated and a lot of relationships between them. So, that approach would produce millions of nodes and leave the existing. Also, when the new node from `CompanyAddress` label is created, wouldn't that create another `HAS_COMPANY_ADDRESS` relationship?

Comment: Yes, each company has only one CompanyAddress with the properties provided in the example

Comment: The problem with this solution is that let's say if I already have a company node without relationships, this approach will create new company node with the relationship. Also if I try to create new relationship, lets say `CompanyInfo`, it will create another company node with the new relationship.

Comment: If you MERGE on the :Company node first (as is done in the updated query), it will match to the already existing company, so the MERGE of the relationship to that already matched company will not create any extra :Company nodes. Likewise if adding :CompanyInfo to an already existing company. You can try it out yourself if you like, with fake data.

Comment: Sorry, I was tired yesterday and made a mistake. The update query works perfectly. Thank you very much :)